# Excel use formula to produce a conditional comma-separated list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array, conditional-statements

I have a dataset in which the right 5 columns indicate with a Y/N if each row applies to that option of 5 potential options:

[image: Table example]

I am looking to add one final column that uses a formula to check for each of the five options if it applies, and then produces a comma-separated list of which apply

> E.g.
>
> Row 1 [Y,N,N,Y,N] > output "Option 1,Option 4"
>
> Row 2 [Y,Y,Y,N,N] > output "Option 1, Option 2, Option 3"

Or, a formula for the yellow cells in this image:

[image: Desired output]

I've tried various forms of array formulae but can't get it going...

Comment: Welcome! You didn't specify your version of Excel - does it have a [**TEXTJOIN() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)?

Comment: As indicated by JohnSUN's comment, this can be accomplished most simply using the [TEXTJOIN()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) and (optionally) [FILTER()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) functions. If you don't have those functions, it's still possible but will be a longer formula. `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(A2:E2="Y",A$1:E$1,""))` or `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(A$1:E$1,A2:E2="Y"))` would work if you adjust the referenced ranges to fit your data.

Comment: That's perfect - didn't know that existed!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(A$1:E$1,A2:E2="Y"))
```

(per comment from Engineer Toast above - thank you!)